# I would like to scrape this webite https://hdyc.neis-one.org/ which has two page login authenticaton

Tags: python, web-scraping, authentication

library('XML')
library('rvest')

login <- "https://www.openstreetmap.org/login?cookie_test=true&referer=%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Foauth_callback%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fhdyc.neis-one.org%252Fland.html%26oauth_token%3DDfkqaWSgSDkhReTb75sOaq22QO6f6txdxFk4qJR7"

pgsession<-html_session(login)

pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]

filled_form<-set_values(pgform, username="********", password="**********")
submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)

html_object <- read_html("https://hdyc.neis-one.org/?**********")

Comment: Please include your code

Answer (score 0):

Try to dockerize your selenium code so that it can run wherever you want. Here are some things that might help.

1. Create a Dockerfile just like [this one](https://github.com/ashutoshsingh101/quora_scraper/blob/master/Dockerfile).
2. Add these lines of code when you initialize your driver.

   ```
   chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
   ```